# Ubuntu 16.04 cannot establish connection to wired or wireless connection

Tags: 16.04, networking, connection

It is a Lenovo Legion Y520 dual boot system with Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10. The wireless connection worked fine this morning and both connections still work in Windows. Had to switch OS at some point, and I know I did an `apt update && apt upgrade` this morning. I've also tried and failed to connect a bluetooth device in Ubuntu (it paired but didn't show up as audio device), but that is the least of my problems now.

All wireless connections are visible, but just won't connect, and the wired connection just shows "Connecting" indefinitely. Rest of the day I got zero development done, so here's my plea for help. HEEELP :)

---

Here's some analysis
So, connections are visible, but I can't ping anything. Also, there's no connection icon in the panel.

Output for `ifconfig`:

```
enp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 54:e1:ad:d2:04:e3  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2790 errors:0 dropped:4 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:198797 (198.7 KB)  TX bytes:108 (108.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:10168 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:10168 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:548164 (548.1 KB)  TX bytes:548164 (548.1 KB)

wlp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e8:2a:44:fe:93:35  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Output for `lshw -C network`:

```
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 32
       serial: e8:2a:44:fe:93:35
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.15.0-48-generic firmware=WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00079-QCARMSWPZ-1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:139 memory:a4200000-a43fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 10
       serial: 54:e1:ad:d2:04:e3
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:19 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a4504000-a4504fff memory:a4500000-a4503fff
```

Some `lspci` stuff:

```
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 31)
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 32)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
```

My `/etc/network/interfaces` looks like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

---

I've tried a bunch of resets and reinstalled `network-manager` and `r8168` driver (`r8168-dkms_8.045.08-2_all.deb`). Also tried to boot from older kernel, but I'm not sure what I expected there.

Any suggestions are appreciated, thanks.

---

**edit**: 
Two things stand out with `dmesg less`:

```
[    1.594537] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
[    1.594545] r8168: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    1.594632] r8168: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[    1.595852] r8168 Gigabit Ethernet driver 8.045.08-NAPI loaded
```

so more `r8168` stuff,

and

```
[    9.946492] audit: type=1400 audit(1557504826.227:38): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper" name="/usr/local/lib/libz.so.1.2.9" pid=1717 comm="nm-dhcp-helper" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
```

as I ran into an opencv problem in the morning, solved by installing `libz.so.1.2.9`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48579743

Comment: I strongly suggest to avoid installing specific versions of libz unless you know exactly what you are doing as its a critical part of system internals and a sure fire way to throw sand into the gearbox ... in-fact on a toy machine its a fun way to watch the system meltdown by installing off the cuff releases of shared libs

Comment: might be of help  https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man7/apparmor.7.html

Comment: Thanks, it was surely a day of frustrations. I'm going to pick this up tomorrow.

Comment: a fresh install ubuntu today using 19.04 is surprisingly stable and noticeably easier to use than prior releases ... if you want to fight to get working 16.04 thats cool however the current release is always better supported and just easier especially for new comers ... If you can I suggest you abandon Microsoft  Window$$$ ... that was so 20th Century ...  to make your life easier you should reformat entire machine and install ubuntu from scratch ... that is the path of least resistance  ... linux is the 21st Century !!!

Comment: Sorry for the late respons. Ended up doing this. Too bad I still need windows for work. But upgrading the ubuntu partition was a breeze, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Basic settings; 
WIRED though - there should be e.g. password and encryption settings for Wifi.
*(I have no wifi on the current computer)*

Check `System settings` > `Network`, it should look similar to this:

[image]

Click `Options` to see these, check all tabs.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response.
Everything is pretty much the same, except for the DNS servers in ```IPv4 Settings``` and Airplane Mode turned off.


Also, the main Network screen only has a Hardware adress: https://imgur.com/utjUcUO


No luck though

Comment: Type `dmesg | less` in a shell and use `/` key to enter things to search for... (q to quit, h for more info about "less"). Check if there is  anything network related, possibly something that reads fault, failed or error

Comment: Two things stood out. See "edit" in main post.

Comment: Seems like a similar problem as https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085930/wifi-stopped-working-on-ubuntu-16-04-after-installing-opencv, so it looks like I have to dive in this rabbit hole. Thanks for pointing me in this direction, keep you posted.